# Python regex match the third line containing a float

Tags: python, regex

I have a list containing those 3 lines repeated n times:

```
Test
Choice : Q1
Expected : 0,5
```

The only value that differ into the list is the third line `Expected : 0,5` the float number can differ from -10 to 10.

I haven't managed to come up with a regular expression to only get the float number inside the third line yet.

I'm not comfortable with regex, what I've managed to dot yet is something like this:

```
(?:^[^\n]*\n?)
```

Here is [my regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9dddLi/1).

Any good suggestion?

Comment: Do you mean you need `\b[0-9]+(?:,[0-9]+)?\b`? See https://regex101.com/r/mbecxX/1

Comment: Indeed it does match with what I need, thanks for your quick answer !

Comment: maybe you should use `Expected : ` in your `regex` - like `Expected : ([0-9,-]*)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
\b[0-9]+(?:,[0-9]+)?\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mbecxX/1).

*Details*:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `[0-9]+` -  one or more digits
- `(?:,[0-9]+)?` - an optional sequence of a comma and one or more digits
- `\b` - a word boundary

Comment: Thanks for your explanations, it works well on every cases.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a regex for a simple task like this:

```
>>> s = 'Expected : 0,5'
>>> value = s.split(':')[-1].strip()
>>> value
'0,5'
```

If you want it to be a float rather than a string:

```
>>> num_value = float(value.replace(',', '.'))
>>> num_value
0.5
```

Comment: @RavinderSingh13: both sides: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip

Comment: Please note that this solution will also fetch `Q1` from the `Choice : Q1` line/string which is not expected (as per OP requirements).